# Ethernet port not blinking in sleep mode although WOL enabled

Tags: centos, wake-on-lan

I have laptop Toshiba A300 with CentOS 7.
I have WOL enabled in BIOS and `ethtool` shows it's enabled:

```
[root@okvmhguest4 ~]# ethtool enp2s0 | grep Wake-on
        Supports Wake-on: pumbg
        Wake-on: g
```

However, after `systemctl suspend` the ethernet port isn't blinking and the laptop does not respond to magic packet.

```
[root@okvmhguest4 ~]# lspci | grep -i Ethernet
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 02)

[root@okvmhguest4 ~]# nmcli connection show "Wired connection 1" | grep wake
802-3-ethernet.wake-on-lan:             64 (magic)
802-3-ethernet.wake-on-lan-password:    --
```

[image]

Comment: Has the BIOS any option to enable WOL?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro yes